# Connect 2 networks through a Linux gateway

Tags: networking, iptables, route, iproute, gateway

I am moving my first steps in Linux networking and I'm a bit stuck on this.

I have 2 private networks 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.3.0/24

And I want to be able to ping the machines from one network to another.

I created 2 VMs with virtual box and assigned the IP addresses 10.0.1.4 and 10.0.3.4. Now since they are not on the same network I cannot ping 10.0.3.4 from 10.0.1.4

Then I created another VM (gateway) with 2 network cards connected to the 2 networks. I assigned the IP addresses as 10.0.1.5 and 10.0.3.5.

Then I've updated the IP tables on 10.0.1.4 typing route default gw 10.0.1.5 and enabled the IP forwarding in the gateway VM.

At this point I was expecting to be able to ping the 10.0.3.4 from 10.0.1.4 but that's not happening.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Everything is symetrical in your setup. Did you do the equivalent actions on the other leaf VM? Can each leaf VM ping its gateway? You have to troubleshout with small steps. Also double check you enabled forwarding in the gateway

Comment: Yes I did exactly the same on the machine in 10.0.3.4 and I am able to ping the gateway from each VM. I have enabled the IP forwarding in the gateway typing echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Comment: Is IP forwarding enabled on the gateway? `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: You should add in the question results from these informations, run on each VM: `ip link show; ip -4 addr show; ip neigh show; ip route show; iptables-save -c`. Perhaps something will appear. Also install tcpdump on each VM and check what is seen.

Comment: Ok I figured it out.  I had 2 issues. 1- I had a wrong route for the default gw on the 10.0.3.4. Once I set this properly the ping worked! 2 - the VM on 10.0.1.4 is an Ubuntu machine which, for some reason, keeps losing the connection and every 20 seconds I have to re-assign the ipaddress with `ifconfig enp0s3 10.0.1.4 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.1.255`. Do you know why this was happening? Anyway my problem is definitely solved now. Thank you so much @A.B for your precious help